# how can i find parent and child relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have one table: Users

> table Fields:
>
> ```
> user_id PK INT AI
>
> user_name VARCHAR (45)
>
> parent_user_id FK INT
> ```

```
Rows:
user_id user_name parent_user_id
1       dave            0
2       john            1
3       pritesh         1
4       larry           3
5       abha            4
```

Please create a query that can tell me the number of steps difference between any two users.

Example:

```
user_names: dave and abha
steps difference: 3
```

Explanation:
dave is parent to pritesh (1 step) pritesh is parent to Larry (2 steps) larry is parent to abha (3 steps).

i have already tried following query:

```
SELECT (CASE
         WHEN (count(T2.user_id) - 1) = -1
             THEN 0
             ELSE (count(T2.user_id) - 1)
   END) as steps
FROM
(
SELECT
    @r AS _id,
    (
    SELECT
        @r := parent_user_id
    FROM
        USER
    WHERE
        user_id = _id
) AS parent_user_id,
@l := @l + 1 AS lvl
FROM
(
SELECT
@r := (select MAX(user_id) from USER),
@l := (select MIN(user_id) from USER)
) vars,
USER h
WHERE
@r <> 0
) T1
JOIN
USER T2
ON
T1._id = T2.user_id
WHERE
   (CASE
   WHEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1) < (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2)
        THEN (T2.user_id BETWEEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1) AND (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2))

   ELSE (T2.user_id BETWEEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2) AND (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1))

   END)
ORDER BY
T1.lvl
DESC
```

Comment: Very similar question already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670470/mysql-parent-child-concept

Comment: @Tommassiov it's a question, not an answer

Comment: Post your query what you try

Comment: @Aaryan I have posted my query in my question. please, tell me what i am doing wrong  in this query

Answer (score 2):

bingo @maulik

I have found your solution to find a number of steps between 2 nodes.
I have made some changes In your query & make it easier.

```
select  count(DISTINCT(parent_user_id)) -1 as Step_Difference
  from    (select * from USER
          order by parent_user_id, user_id) products_sorted,
         (select @pv := 0) initialisation
  where   find_in_set(parent_user_id, @pv)
  and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_id))
  AND
  (CASE
      WHEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1) < (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2) AND  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM USER WHERE(SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name = _name1) IN( SELECT parent_user_id FROM USER) ) > 0
          THEN (user_id BETWEEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1) AND (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2))

      WHEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2) < (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1) AND  (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM USER WHERE(SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name = _name2) IN( SELECT parent_user_id FROM USER) ) > 0
            THEN (user_id BETWEEN (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name2) AND (SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE user_name= _name1))

      ELSE (user_id = 1)

  END)
```